# Edit a user's "websites" using the Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, web, publish

How do I use the Graph API to edit a user's list of websites on their "About Me" page?

I have used the API to a user's website, their friend's websites, and post to a user's profile feed, but I cannot work out how to use it to add a website to the list?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the `user_website` or `friends_website` permission will allow you to access a Facebook user's website field, there is currently no Graph API call that allows programmatic editing of this field.

The Graph API documentation on [Users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) contains both "fields" and "connections." While connections can be modified by sending POST requests, fields are mostly read-only. Since a user's website is one of the latter, it cannot be edited.

Comment: Is there another Facebook API that allows editing of the user's website? For example the Open Graph API?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the "Open Graph API". Facebook's Open Graph is part of the Graph API. They both use the same API endpoints (e.g. graph.facebook.com) and have similar syntax and responses.